# How to make my application refresh my content (JSON) automatically?

Tags: android, json, cordova

I'm making an application where I want my content to be updating without updating the whole application through a marketplace.

I made a JSON file where I put all my content in and it works great if I open the app on my mobile device. But when I update my content in the JSON file, the content inside the app is not automatically downloaded.

Also, I want to make sure that the content from the last JSON file that was downloaded is still visible in the application. Thereby the content is still visible while the device is offline.

Also good to know is that I'm using Phonegap, and I think that I can use the local storage API from Phonegap to store the JSON file so the content inside the application is still visible when the device is offline. Is this possible? And how do I make sure this JSON file is updated when I change the content??

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, it's possible -- it's done all the time. I retagged your question to include phonegap, but as it is, your question shows virtually no research effort, and you might want to read up on phonegap documentation before asking a question on something this basic.

Answer (score 0):

So for your content to be visible, you must use a view. You need a view for the latest content and a view for the historical content. Each time you update content you must

- update the historical view by first calling `historicalView.removeAllViews()` and then `historicalView.addView(updatedHistory);`
- then update the `latestContentView` the same way:`latestContentView.removeAllViews()` and then `latestContentView.addView(latestContent);`

Comment: You misunderstood the question.